# Detecting MessageBoxes created by 3rd party DLLs

Tags: winapi, messagebox, setwindowshookex

I'm loading 3rd party DLLs and sometimes they open MessageBox windows that stops the flow of the application, I want to be able to detect when such thing happens.

I'm trying to use `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_CBT` but my callback does not get called.

I tried calling it this way:

```
SetWindowsHookEx (WH_CBT, myCallback, NULL, 0);
```

But it didn't worked.

What should be the right call for this function?

Comment: You are not going to inject a hook by passing NULL and 0 to the function.  Improve your error handling, don't ignore api function return values.

Comment: I also tried SetWindowsHookEx (WH_CBT, myCallback, GetModuleHandle (0), GetCurrentThreadId()) but to no avail.

Comment: You are just randomly trying stuff.  A global hook like WH_CBT requires a DLL that can be injected into other processes.  That will never be GetModuleHandle(0), you cannot inject your own EXE.  Visit the google hits, this is well covered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting creation of a MessageBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084579/detecting-creation-of-a-messagebox) Oh wait, you're the person who asked that question. Did you read the documentation I linked to? As Hans says, just randomly trying stuff isn't going to make it work.

Comment: Both the answer here and in the other post will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the WM_ENTERIDLE message to detect if there's any MessageBox window, simply check with FindWindowEx().

This is C# but idea doesn't change:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d3f89686-e4d0-4bb1-9052-31abef2a9d2a